# Split a string and create dummies in R

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have something like `val1` where the separator is `,`. I would like to split `val1` and then create dummies. how to get around with this. many thanks in advance.

```
val1 <- c("ab, cd, ef", "", "gh")
val2 <- c('John','Peter','Jolie')
data <- data.frame(val1,val2); data
```

Expected Answer

```
      ab cd ef gh
John  1   1  1  0
Peter 0   0  0  0
Jolie 0   0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, use `strsplit` to split the 'val1' based on the `,` and any space following into a `list`, set the names of the `list` with 'val2', `stack` it to a two column data.frame and apply `table`

```
out <- table(stack(setNames(strsplit(data$val1, ",\\s+"), data$val2))[2:1])
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
      ab cd ef gh
John   1  1  1  0
Peter  0  0  0  0
Jolie  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: [2:1] is a reverse version of default, I guess. cool. thank you very much.